# Undergrad Research Journals in Physics

Tags: experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, education

I want to know if undergraduate research journals, in general and specifically in Physics, have (or keep) measure of impact factor? If no, then how do you measure the quality of the journal and work published there in? I am interested in journal which accept publications in Experimental Physics.

Answer (score 0):

Assessing the quality of a paper always needs reading (or at least having a look at) the paper. Much of this work is never cited. Any important results will be also be written up by the supervisor, and then it is generally that paper that will be cited.

In some way, this is similar to articles about educational physics: lots of teachers may read them and use them. Or articles in applied physics. Publications with low numbers of citations may have proven to be very useful to engineers, teachers, or students.

Comment: Yes but impact factor of a certain journal or a certain author is very commonly used as a measure of the quality of their work and the quality of the journal.  But, guessing from your answer, it does not exist for undergrad research journals. But then why do these journals exist and why publish at all?